# AS3 - zoom gesture get zoom direction?

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming, gesture

I've been searching for a way to do what seems like a very simple task. 
I have a mousewheel zoom function which works perfectly because the delta value is reset to 0 after each function. 
The zoom gesture it seems is not so simple?
My issue is that I'm trying to create a dynamic scale limit (max zoom will be different for each level). and the zoom is getting stuck at the max scale that I'm setting and can't be zoomed out. I'm trying to use the e.scaleX property to identify the direction so that you can zoom out, but it's not working properly.

Thanks for any help! 
the code:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom); 
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{ 
    var zoomAmountGesture:Number = 0;
    zoomAmountGesture = e.scaleX;

    if (zoomAmountGesture <= 0){
container.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
container.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
        if (container.scaleX < 1){
            container.scaleX = 1;
            container.scaleY = 1
        }
    }
    if (zoomAmountGesture > 0){
    container.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
    container.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
        if(4* BlockSize * container.scaleX > StageWidth){
            trace("zoom too big");
            var newBlockScale:Number = StageWidth / 3;
            var newBoardScale:Number = newBlockScale / BlockSize;
            trace("newBoardScale = " + newBoardScale);
            container.scaleX = newBoardScale;
            container.scaleY = newBoardScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick read of **TransformGestureEvent**.

The next block has no meaning, because the event **scaleX** and **scaleY** properties are 1-based:

```
if (zoomAmountGesture <= 0){
```

Then, you should probably start with the following:

```
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    var aScale:Number = container.scaleX * e.scaleX;
    if (aScale < 1) aScale = 1;
    if (aScale > PredefinedMaxScale) aScale = PredefinedMaxScale;

    container.scaleX = aScale;
    container.scaleY = aScale;
}
```

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because I think it does answer my question. I'm still having trouble with my specific situation though which I realize I didn't explain enough or provide enough of the code. The issue I'm having is that var BlockSize changes (gets smaller) every level, so the max zoom isn't a set amount, but rather based on the relative block size for that level. So the max zoom for level 1 might be 1.2 but the max zoom for level 10 or 20 might be 4 or 5. I'm trying to figure out the logic and I think I'm almost there and your answer did help me move this forward so thank you!!

Comment: @ZacKenny You can actually set max zoom via array of values, or even calculate it on each level start with **stage.stageWidth / BlockSize**.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help @Organis!

    function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
 var newBlockScale:Number = BlockSize * 4; 
 var PredefinedMaxScale:Number = StageWidth / newBlockScale;
 trace("PredefinedMaxScale = " + PredefinedMaxScale);
    var aScale:Number = container.scaleX * e.scaleX;
    if (aScale < 1) {aScale = 1;}
    if (aScale > PredefinedMaxScale) {aScale = PredefinedMaxScale;}
    container.scaleX = aScale;
    container.scaleY = aScale;
}